# Remove edittext indicator (underline) - Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to remove underline of TextInputLayout. Its almost removed but showing little parts on start and on the end (black). It shows only when activated Screen below

[image]

style:

```
<style name="EditTextLoginRegister" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/greyLight2</item>
        <item name="startIconTint">@color/greyLight2</item>
        <item name="endIconTint">@color/greyLight2</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/violet</item>
    </style>
```

and the TextInputLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_email_login"
        style="@style/EditTextLoginRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/e_mail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_header_login"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_user">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/greyLight" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `boxStrokeWidthFocused` to your style

```
<style name="EditTextLoginRegister" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- Other attributes -->
    <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>

</style>
```

Admittedly, this is the most difficult part -> styling Material design views.
In Android Studio, it is possible to get `AutoComplete` options, and I usually go through the complete list and try out various items.

[image]

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks. I agree that Material design styling is not so friendly.